# Window not visible despite running in background

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a macro that I'm trying to run through Access that will open up an excel sheet, do some actions on it, and then leave the sheet open.

I have most of it working, with the exception of not being able to get my excel document to open visibly. If I check the task manager, an excel process is running in the background so something does happen, just nothing that I can physically see.

I've attempted to sample some code found through stackoverflow and other resources, which I'm sure you'll see some of that in my current code. But I tried for about an hour with no avail.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim MySheetPath As String
Dim Xl As Excel.Application
Dim XlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim XlSheet As Excel.Worksheet

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
'allowing selection of the time
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

fd.AllowMultiSelect = False

If fd.Show = True Then
    If fd.SelectedItems(1) <> vbNullString Then
        MySheetPath = fd.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
Else
    End
End If

Set Xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set XlBook = GetObject(MySheetPath)

ShowaWindow (MySheetPath)

Set XlSheet = XlBook.Worksheets(1)

XlSheet.Rows(2).EntireRow.Insert
XlSheet.Range("D2") = "ABC"

Set Xl = Nothing
Set XlBook = Nothing
Set XlSheet = Nothing

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
Set fd = Nothing
MsgBox "Error " & Err & ": " & Error(Err)

End Sub

Sub ShowaWindow(sFileName As String)
Dim oWb As Workbook

Set oWb = GetObject(sFileName)

For Each oWb In Workbooks
    If LCase(oWb.Name) <> LCase(sFileName) Then
        oWb.Windows(1).Visible = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Ideally I would like to be able to see the worksheet appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set XlBook = GetObject(MySheetPath)
```

This is wrong. Don't use `GetObject` to open the workbook, use the `Excel.Application` instance you just created:

```
Set XlBook = Xl.Workbooks.Open(MySheetPath)
```

Later you iterate all opened workbooks:

```
 For Each oWb In Workbooks
```

But that's not the `Workbooks` collection from the `Xl` application instance, it's the `Workbooks` collection from the instance that's currently running your code - you need to qualify it with the `Xl` object:

```
Private Sub ShowaWindow(ByVal app As Excel.Application, ByVal sFileName As String)
    '...
    For Each oWb In app.Workbooks
```

Also, [make the app instance visible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56671456/1188513) after you created it, and don't forget to invoke `XlBook.Close` and `Xl.Quit` to properly tear down that EXCEL.EXE process when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set Xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Xl.Visible=True
```

You don't need to put it immediately after creating the object, just before you set the object to Nothing.

Comment: All this does for me is load a barren excel document. It doesn't even have a grid.

Comment: I attached an imgur link to the result [link](https://imgur.com/a/0HkeFwU)

Comment: @CryingOverVBA that's not a "barren excel document", it's the Excel application *without any document loaded*. Use `Xl.Workbooks.Open` to open a document, or `Xl.Workbooks.Add` to create one.

Comment: @CryingOverVBA So I spend the time to answer your question and rather than given your response politely you moan that it doesn't do what you think it will do in a rude and aggressive manner.  Not really the way to get people on your side.

Comment: @Gareth I wasn't trying to be rude or aggressive there, I myself don't see it phrased like that. 

Although, apologies if it was perceived that way.